# Does using more external files, opposed to cramming everything into one file, reduce run-time-efficiency?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, performance

I am relatively new to web design and the world of jquery, javascript and php. I guess this question would also suit css style sheets as well. Is it better to have everything stuffed into one "external document"? Or does this not affect the run time speeds?

Also to go along with this. Is it wrong, or less efficient, to use php in places where jquery / javascript could be implemented? Which of the two languages is generally faster?

Comment: you seem to be confusing client side and server-side. Also pure speed is never the only factor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should look at it would be to load the minimum resources required initially which would be needed on page load, not everything.  Make sure you group all of these resources together into a single file, and minify them.

Once your page is loaded, you can thereafter load other resources on demand.  For e.g a modal, which does not need to be immediately visible can be loaded at a later point of time, when user does some action, and it needs to be shown.  This is called lazy loading.  But when you do load any module on demand, make sure you load all of its resources together and minified as well.

It's important to structure your code correctly and define the way you batch files together for concatenation and minification.  It will help you save on performance by optimizing the number of calls made to the server.

About PHP and JavaScript, I would say in general JavaScript is faster than PHP, but it depends on your application, as one runs on the server and other on the client.  So if you are doing too heavy and memory intensive operations, the browser might limit your capabilities.  If that is not a problem, go ahead with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of different factors that come into play here.  Ultimately, it is better to call the least amount of resources possible to make the site run faster.  Many sites that check page speed will dock points if you call a ton of resources.  However, you don't want to go insane condensing and try to cram everything into a single file either...  The best way to approach it is to use as few files as possible while maintaining a logical organization.

For example, maybe you're using a few different JS libraries... well merging those all into one would eventually get confusing and hard to update so it makes sense to keep them all separate.  However, you can keep all your custom JS where you call those libraries in one separate file.  This can even be applied to images.  Let's say you're uploading 5 different social media icons and 5 different hover states for them.  Well, instead of making the site call 10 different files, use a sprite and just call one.

You can also do things like use google's hosted libraries: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/  Many sites use these and therefore many users already have these resources cached which means they don't need to freshly load the libraries when visiting your site.  It's very helpful for things like jQuery.

Another thing to keep in mind is minifying those files.  Any library you use should have a minified version and you should use that as opposed to a full version.  While you should keep unminified copies of your work around, whatever ends up on the live site should be minified to help with page speed.  Here are a few resources for that: https://cssminifier.com/ https://javascript-minifier.com/  If you're using WP, there's tons of plugins out there that have similar functions like WP Fastest Cache.

You php/js/jquery question I can't really weigh in on too heavily. As mentioned, the base difference between php and JS ist whether the requests are client-side or server-side.  Personally, I use whatever is prevalent in the project and whatever works best for your changes.  For example, if you're working with variables and transferring data, PHP can be a really great

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful!